# How to remove raw post body from Sample results in http post-processor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario with upload of 1.5 Gb file and I use distributed jmeter testing. I.e the request data don't make a sense for my tests, so I don't want the post data being transferred from slave (agent) jmeter to master (server), However, in the beanshell post-processor I haven't fount any API for removing the raw post data from the http sampler.

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setPostBodyRaw-boolean- seems not be the case. So, how one can remove the large post data from the sampler in Jmeter in order to make distributed test work more robust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, i couldn't figure out how to exclude post data from jmeter slave-to-master communication; I had to write own JSR-223 Sampler which does the http request called form Java code using HttpConnection class and then manipulates the sample data from Java code. Http Sampler didn't worked for me.

such kind of sampler are good because it also allows to read files and send them to http post body using Input/OutputStreams and buffers, thus we no longer require memory for the whole file to be uploaded that HttpSampler uses to allocate.

Example sampler code is:

```
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
    String line = null;
    try {
       URL url = new URL("http://${url}/api/v2.0/datasets");
           URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();               
        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException ("URL is not an Https URL");
        }               
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_161)");
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(500 * 1000);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                         httpConn.getOutputStream());


        out.write("--boundary\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write("dataset${__time}\r\n");
        out.write("--boundary\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\"\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write("${user_token}\r\n");
        out.write("--boundary\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sep\"\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write("${separator}\r\n");
        out.write("--boundary\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csv_file\"; filename=\"filename.csv\"\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.write("\r\n");
        String filepath="files//${datasetFileName}";
        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader fin =
                new BufferedReader(isr); 
       String bufString;                  
       while ((bufString = fin.readLine()) != null) {
             out.write(bufString+"r\n");
        }  
        out.write("--boundary--");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

       InputStream _is;
       log.info(""+httpConn.getResponseCode());
       SampleResult.setResponseCode(httpConn.getResponseCode()+"");
       if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {         
       _is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
       } else {
       /* error from server */
       _is = httpConn.getInputStream();
       }
       if (_is!=null)
       {
       BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(_is)
                    );                   

        String decodedString;
        String accumulate="";
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
             accumulate=accumulate+"\n"+decodedString;
           log.info(decodedString);
        }       
        SampleResult.setResponseData(accumulate);
       }
       else
       {
        SampleResult.setResponseData("No data from server");
       }
       }
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       log.info(e.getMessage());
    } catch( SocketTimeoutException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       log.info(e.getMessage());
     }    
    finally {//httpConn.disconnect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. By default JMeter should not transfer the POST data from slave to master. If it does double check your [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) and make sure that `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` is set to `csv` and you're storing only those metrics which are absolutely required

---

2. Just FYI: you're looking at wrong function, if you want to remove the file from the "Files Upload" section programmatically you need to do something like [`sampler.setHTTPFiles(new HTTPFileArg\[0\]);`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setHTTPFiles-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg:A-)

   Be aware that your file upload will stop working after this change.

   3. [Starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because [Groovy performs much better than other scripting languages](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so going forward make sure to use Groovy.

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for your answer! I'm using jmeter under the Taurus hood, so I'm not sure about the default value of jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format passed to slaves behind the scenes. What may happen if it is set to xml? In xml I see jtl having post data inside.

Comment: For point 2, the file upload is configured via Body Data set up, not Files Upload. Should the API you are pointed help too for this kind of configuring post body cleanup?

Comment: `sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()`

Comment: Dmitri, with sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments() in JSR 223 postprocessor I'm getting 1) Post body seems not being removed from the first request 2) is removed BEFORE the all next requests, so it try to send http request withour required POST data. how cat I make it work strictly as post-processor just handling the previous sample, but not affecting future samples?

Comment: the only code in postprocessor is import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()

Comment: Dmitri, i also have to mention that in post form the data doesn't looks like "key=value" pairs. Would Arguments api as well as removeArguments() work in that case?

Comment: as for master-slave communication, I have set jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv for both master and slave properties, but still observing the large traffic from slave to master at the end of the http request. any thoughts?

Comment: jmeter 4.0 for both master and slave

Comment: Check out http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Test-Log, my expectation is that you have this configured to `xml` and having a shit ton of unnecessary data stored

Comment: i have set up execution:
- write-xml-jtl: none , but i'm not sure, does it affects only master (i.e. taurus doesn't write xml itself) or is it distributed to jmeter too (looks like is not, since slave still send 1.5 Gb data to master, even configured to send csv via properties)

Comment: Dmitiri, according to taurus support, the settings are applied to local master jmeter only and not propagated to slaves: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codename-taurus/6fRgx1vWnq8

Comment: Dmitri, what about httpclient4.max_body_retain_size parameter? the descrition says "Max size in bytes of PUT body to retain in result sampler. Bigger results will be clipped." So am I right, that at least for PUT body it comes to result sampler? will it work for POST?

Comment: temporarily I have set up the write-xml-jtl: error on master in order to understand where the huge data in the results sample is persisted. it is stored under queryString element of sample. And i don't see any API to manipulate it, just getter ((( so I believe that in agent-master communication this data as a part of queryString still resides in the samples sent to master, despite of other settings I have done

Comment: I also tried to output queryString in JSR223 post-processor and and replace all the body of request with empty string, but 1) queryString is logged as empty and replace semmes doesnt' help:import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
log.info(sampler.getPort()+"");
log.info(sampler.getQueryString());
sampler.replace(".*","",true);
log.info(sampler.getQueryString());